# Update Values:Output message

Tags: excel, vba

I have run this code successfully with one data set. With a new data set with the same format for all variables I get an "Update Values: Output message. I have entered the file name of a blank workbook in the Filename dialogue box and nothing gets written to it.
The Unique Records sheet is updated before the programme breaks and I get the Update Values: Output message
Would appreciate some help
Max

```
With Sheets("Data").Select
    Unique_NHI = Range("f2:" & "f" & Data_len)
    unique_assess = Range("e2:" & "e" & Data_len)
    Unique_reason = Range("a2:" & "a" & Data_len)
    Unique_unit = Range("g2:" & "g" & Data_len)
End With

For x = 1 To Data_len - 1
    Temp_String = Format(CDate(unique_assess(x, 1)), "YYYY-MM-DD")
    First_Data(x, 1) = Unique_NHI(x, 1) & Temp_String
    First_Data(x, 2) = Unique_NHI(x, 1)
    First_Data(x, 3) = ""
    First_Data(x, 4) = unique_assess(x, 1)
    First_Data(x, 5) = Unique_reason(x, 1)
    First_Data(x, 6) = ""
    First_Data(x, 7) = ""
    First_Data(x, 8) = ""
    First_Data(x, 9) = Unique_unit(x, 1)
Next x



With Sheets("Unique Records").Select
    Set rng2 = Range("A2:z1000000")
    rng2.Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Set rng3 = Range("A2:i" & Data_len)
    rng3 = First_Data
```

Comment: I've not heard of the `Update Values: Output message` - can you provide some more info about it, maybe some documentation to read?

Comment: It is a prompt to open a file